# how to join tables sql server

Tags: sql-server

Im having some trouble with joining two tables. This is what my two tables look like:

Table 1

```
Customer_ID   CustomerName   Add. 
1000          John Smith
1001          Mike Coles
1002          Sam Carter
```

Table 2

```
Sensor_ID     Location      Temp    CustIDFK
1000          NY            70
1002          NY            70
1000          ...           ...
1001
1001
1002
```

Desired:

```
Sensor_ID     Location      Temp    CustIDFK
1000          NY            70      John Smith
1002          NY            70      Sam Carter
1000          ...           ...     John Smith
1001                                Mike Coles
1001
1002
```

I have made Customer_ID from table 1 my primary key, created custIDFK in table 2 and set that as my foreign  key. I am really new to sql server so I am still having trouble with the whole relationship piece of it. My goal is to match one customer_ID with one Sensor_ID. The problem is that the table 2 does not have "unique IDs" since they repeat so I cant set that to my foreign key. I know I will have to do either an inner join or outer join, I just dont know how to link the sensor id with customer one. I was thinking of giving my sensor_ID a unique ID but the data that is being inserted into table 2 is coming from another program. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your data, it looks like the value of `Sensor_ID` should instead exist in `CustIDFK`.  I would then suggest making `Sensor_ID` an identity value within your sensor table, and make that value the primary key of this table.

If you want to associate the two tables, you should be able to simply join on `Customer_ID` and `CustIDFK` once it has been properly populated with the value currently in `Sensor_ID`.

```
SELECT
    t1.Customer_ID, t1.CustomerName, t2.Location, t2.Temp
From
    Table1 t1 JOIN
    Table2 t2 ON t1.Customer_ID = t2.CustIDFK
```

Comment: so I understand that the data in Sensor_ID should be in CustIDFK. However, I dont get why Sensor_ID would be changed into an identity value. If my data in Sensor_ID is in CustIDFK, shouldn't I make that my primary key?

Comment: A primary key is a value (or combination of values) that uniquely identifies a row in a table.  Since there is a one-to-many relationship between Customer and Sensor, Customer_ID is just a foreign key (A different table's primary key) in your sensor table... not a primary key within the sensor table.  Since you'll want to have some sort of PK for the sensor table, I suggest changing sensor_id to an auto-generated identity value so that it uniquely identifies each row in your sensor table.

Comment: ok that makes more sense now. But I if say, change Sensor_ID from datatype int to numeric or uniqueidentifier, set it as a primary as you suggested, I would not be able to make Customer_ID(int datatype) because the datatype does not match.

Comment: Sensor_ID can be an int... it doesn't have to be a GUID.  Also, the datatype for the PK of the sensor table doesn't need to be the same datatype for the PK of the customer table... the two IDs aren't related to each other in any way.

Comment: I have set Sensor_ID as an identity value with increments of 1 and datatype int and as a PK. I understand the part of doing the join Customer_ID and CustIDFK. However, on my relationship diagram, whenever I try to link my Sensor_ID with Customer_ID (in order to set Customer_ID as my FK, I get an error saying: the following may have not matched: datatype, length, or precision

Comment: Sensor_ID has no relation to Customer_ID.  They are two different values that track to different things... the only relation you have is between Customer_ID and CustIDFK.

Comment: ok so I guess im thinking more in terms of PK and FK. Being that the data of Sensor_ID now populates in CustIDFK and Sensor_ID now = PK, what would be the FK in my Customer Table?

Comment: Never mind that last question Michael, I figured it out, I was trying to match them using the database diagram when I simply had to do the join statement you posted above and specify a "where" clause. Thank you very much for your help, it has really helped my understanding a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure where you actually see the problem, a simple natural join should do:

```
SELECT T1.CustomerName, T2.SensorID, T2.Location, T2.Temp
FROM Table1 AS T1, Table2 AS T2
WHERE T1.Customer_ID = T2.CustIDFK
```

Since you do not join on the `ID`column of Table 2, but instead you join on the foreign key it does not matter that there is no unique key in Table 2.

Comment: yes the code you provided would probably do the trick for me. However, when I execute it, it shows me the name of the columns with no data. My problem relies on how I have mapped the relationships.