# Simple SQL Select Statement

Tags: sql, select

```
create table Company(cname varchar(30) primary key, country varchar(30));

insert into Company values('GizmoWorks','USA');
insert into Company values('Canon','Japan');
insert into Company values('Hitachi','Japan');
insert into Company values('BizWorks', NULL);
insert into Company values('MonkeyBiz', NULL);

create table Product(pname varchar(30) primary key, price float, category varchar(30), manufacturer varchar(30) references Company);

insert into Product values('Gizmo',19.99,'Gadgets','GizmoWorks');
insert into Product values('PowerGizmo',29.99,'Gadgets','GizmoWorks');
insert into Product values('SingleTouch',149.99,'Photography','Canon');
insert into Product values('Multitouch',203.99,'Household','Hitachi');
insert into Product values('SuperGizmo',49.99, 'Gadgets', 'Hitachi');
insert into Product values('Gizmo-Plus',NULL,'Gadgets','GizmoWorks');
insert into Product values('SingleTouch-Light',89.99,'Photography','Canon');
insert into Product values('SingleTouch++',79.99,'Photography','MonkeyBiz');
```

I have a these two tables and I am supposed to retrieve the list of names of all products whose manufacturer is based in Japan. I am new to SQL and am not sure how to do this. Can someone explain this to me?

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT pname
FROM Company, Product
WHERE country='Japan' AND pname='manufacturer'
ORDER BY pname;
```

Comment: Search on `Sql Inner Join`

Comment: @Nathan better is to pass reference on product table of country{FK}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to join tables sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9876582/how-to-join-tables-sql-server)

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use simple `JOIN` to make your expect.

```
SELECT pname
FROM Company c 
JOIN Product p on c.cname = p.manufacturer
WHERE country='Japan'
```

**NOTE**

1. you can try to figure out, which columns can connect two tables then use 
   SQL `JOIN` to make it, For example there are relationship from `Company.cname = Product.manufacturer`.
2. The `,` in between your two tables is mean `CROSS JOIN`, that is an old-style syntax. I would suggest advice use that, because `JOIN` will clearer about tables relationship.