# SQL: Getting current dates price of a product and product code

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 3 tables and I need to get a listing of product codes and their current prices.
Product table has the product name (string) and it's code (integer), Manufacturer table has the product name (string) and manufacturers code (integer) for it and the Pricing table has the manufacturers code (integer) for the products, price (numeric) and a date (date).
I don't have much experience with SQL beyond the basics and I can't really figure out how to get the proper listing.

Comment: you will need to learn how to use JOIN. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html
basically you will need at least a column with (usually) the id from the other table you want to join

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to join tables sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9876582/how-to-join-tables-sql-server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just built you a example in case you need it to learn :)

Product

```
+----+----------------+
| id |      name      |
+----+----------------+
|  1 | GFORCE TITAN   |
|  2 | GFORCE 770     |
|  3 | GFORCE 1060 TI |
+----+----------------+
```

Manufacturer

```
+----+----------+
| id |   name   |
+----+----------+
|  1 | Gigabyte |
|  2 | Asus     |
|  3 | MSI      |
+----+----------+
```

Prices

```
+----+-------+-----------------+------------+
| id | price | manufacturer_id | product_id |
+----+-------+-----------------+------------+
|  1 |  1000 |               1 |          1 |
|  2 |   600 |               1 |          2 |
|  3 |   400 |               2 |          2 |
|  4 |   300 |               3 |          3 |
+----+-------+-----------------+------------+
```

And you should query something like this:

```
SELECT p.price, m.name as manufacturer, pr.name as product
FROM Prices p
JOIN Manufacturer m ON p.manufacturer_id = m.id
JOIN Product pr ON p.product_id = pr.id
ORDER BY p.price DESC
```

Result would be:

```
+----+-------+--------------+----------------+
| id | price | manufacturer |    product     |
+----+-------+--------------+----------------+
|  1 |  1000 | Gigabyte     | GFORCE TITAN   |
|  2 |   600 | Gigabyte     | GFORCE 770     |
|  3 |   400 | Asus         | GFORCE 770     |
|  4 |   300 | MSI          | GFORCE 1060 TI |
+----+-------+--------------+----------------+
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! The example did help me understand.